# Augmented reality with wikitude sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am developing an augmented reality app using wikitude sdk. I am quiet new with this sdk. I have implemented everything as per the sdk documentation guidelines. But I can't able to plot the POI points in the AR-Browser view. For generating the POI points I used the following codes.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)generatePois:(NSUInteger)numberOfPois
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSMutableArray *poiArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfPois];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPois; ++i) {
        objGlobalDatas=[arrayItems objectAtIndex:i];

        WTPoi *poi = [[WTPoi alloc] init];
        NSString *strId=objGlobalDatas.arId;
        NSInteger poiId=[strId integerValue];
        poi.id = poiId;
        poi.name = objGlobalDatas.name;
        NSLog(@"poi name =%@",objGlobalDatas.name);
        poi.detailedDescription = objGlobalDatas.poi_description;
       // poi.type =  i%3; // set the type from 0->2->0->2...
        poi.type=1;
        NSString *strLat=objGlobalDatas.latitude;
        NSString *strLng=objGlobalDatas.longitude;
        float lan=[strLat doubleValue];
        float lng=[strLng doubleValue];
        poi.latitude = lan ;//+ WT_RANDOM(-0.01, 0.01); // set the latitude around your current location
        poi.longitude = lng;// + WT_RANDOM(-0.01, 0.01);
        poi.altitude = YOUR_CURRENT_ALTITUDE + WT_RANDOM(0, 200); // altitude offset
        poi.poiimg=objGlobalDatas.poi_indicator_image;

        poi.weburl=objGlobalDatas.website;
        poi.distance=objGlobalDatas.distance;
        [poiArray addObject:poi];
        [poi release];

    }
    NSLog(@"check =%@",poiArray);
    return poiArray;
}
```

I called this function after fetching the data of POI points by parsing a JSON link. In the poiArray I am getting three objects around my current latitude and longitude.But not showing in the AR-Browser view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this all code related to the Wikitude SDK api? If so, you're missing the `[architectView callJavaScript:@"*jsonString*"]` call. This call will load the places, defined in an json string, to be loaded in AR. Have a closer look at the SimpleARBrowser sample. It demonstrates all necessary steps to load your places in AR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the architecture,html file which loads the json objects